# How to capture the status of a gunzip operation into a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am a novice in shell scripting.I have an unzip operation at the very beginning and then follow a sequence of steps.I would like to move to these steps only if the gunzip operation was successful.

towards that end i have a very simple script right now

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x -e
x=$(gunzip myfile.dat.gz)
echo "X is " $x
```

the output is

```
-bash-3.2$ ./unzipper.sh
++ gunzip myfile.dat.gz
+ x=
+ echo 'X is '
X is
```

I was expecting x to have a 0/non zero status code and based on that would have wanted to use a if condition to carry on with the next.
It doesn't look like this is correct.

Can you please help me with how to do this?

Comment: `$()` captures program *output* not exit status. Exit status is in the `$?` variable but can be directly checked in an `if` statment. `if command; then`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely what you want to do is:

```
#!/bin/bash
if gunzip myfile.dat.gz; then
# What you want to do on success goes here
fi
```

At least, that is the simplest solution. `set -e` has a lot of subtle results; it's not recommended.

If you really want to save the status code of the `gunzip`, you can use `$?` immediately after the command:

```
#!/bin/bash
gunzip myfile.dat.gz
gunzip_status=$?
# Do some stuff whether or not gunzip succeeded
if ((gunzip_status==0)); then
  # Do some stuff only if gunzip succeeded
else
  # Do some stuff only if gunzip failed
fi
# What you want to do on success goes here
fi
```

Comment: Note that in some cases, gunzip can succeed, but with warnings and an exit status of 2: http://www.gzip.org/index.html#faq8